# SimpleCursorAdapter not returning position

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I searched stackoverflow for similar questions. None of the solutions seem to work.

This is my CustomAdapter class.

```
public class ContactAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

Context cont;

public ContactAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
        int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, 0);
    cont = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(cont, position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }); 

    return view;
}
}
```

As per docs I should get position of the current item in toast. But it throws the following exceptions.

```
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:265)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:265)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at com.example.databaseproject.ContactAdapter$1.onClick(ContactAdapter.java:34)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
08-13 13:46:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(5980):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `position` is an int and  `Toast.makeText` method's second parameter( if it is  int) must be a resource id.  So here, there is no Resource with id `position` and you will get `Resources$NotFoundException`

How to fix it?

Just cast it to string  by `position + ""`

Use this code

```
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(cont, position+"",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have passed an `int` value in `Toast`, that leads to exception

change your `Toast` as follow..

```
Toast.makeText(cont, String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```